# Join two tables having in final table value (or null) for every id

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's assume I have table1:

```
id Column2 Column3 Column4
1   YES     NO      NO
2   NO      YES     YES
3   NO      YES     NO
4   YES     YES     NO 
5   NO      NO      NO
```

and I have table2:

```
 id  Column5
    1  NO
    2  YES
    3  NO
    6  YES 
    7  YES
```

I want to join them to have output like this.

```
 id Column2 Column3 Column4  Column5
    1   YES     NO      NO    NO  
    2   NO      YES     YES   YES
    3   NO      YES     NO    NO
    4   YES     YES     NO    null
    5   NO      NO      NO    null
    6   null    null    null   YES
    7   null    null    null   YES
```

Which type of join should I use?

I am currently using Oracle 12c

Comment: `left join` is the answer to your question.

Comment: No it is not `full outer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you are looking for the exact output, then you can use `COALESCE` along with `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
select COALESCE(A.ID,B.ID) ID,COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
from Table1 A full outer join Table2 B
ON A.id = B.id
order by a.id asc
```

[image]

Without `COALESCE` and not selecting columns specifically :

[image]

Comment: Actually having exact table like table1 - coalesce1 and like table2 - coalesce2 executing: select COALESCE(A.ID, B.ID) ID,column2,column3,column4
from coalesce1 A full outer join coalesce2 b
ON A.id = B.id
order by id asc;   does not contain column5 from coalesce2 (table2)

Comment: UPDATE: this, will produce output I would like to have: select COALESCE(A.ID, B.ID) ID,column2,column3,column4,b.COLUMN5
from coalesce1 A full outer join coalesce2 b
ON A.id = B.id
order by id asc;

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do a `full outer join`. Note the `NULL` in line 4/5 for the right table and in 6/7 for the left table.

Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.id;
```

Comment: Please do review the output of your query in below screenshot -2 .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2
USING ( ID )
```